# CA signed cert when using helm to install Artifactory on k8s

Tags: kubernetes-helm, artifactory

I am using helm to install Artifcatory on k8s. The helm CLI which I use is:

```
helm upgrade --install artifactory --namespace artifactory jfrog/artifactory
```

The installation is completed successfully. But the cert installed on the Nginx pod is a self-signed cert and also the subject alternative name of cert is artifactory.svc, which doesn't match the DNS name of Artifactory.

Is there any way that I can change the cert which the Nginx pod will use pre-installation or post-installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Helm chart while performing SSL offload in the LoadBalancer layer of Nginx as below.

```
nginx:
    https:
      enabled: false
    service:
      ssloffload: true
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:xx-xxxx:xxxxxxxx:certificate/xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"

helm upgrade --install artifactory -f artifactory-ssl-values.yaml --namespace artifactory center/jfrog/artifactory
helm upgrade --install artifactory-ha -f artifactory-ssl-values.yaml --namespace artifactory-ha center/jfrog/artifactory-ha
```

Other advanced configs here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Helm+Charts+for+Advanced+Users